# How to add an attribute to the resulting xml exported from excel using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file which exports xml based on the contents of a certain sheet. I am not the author of this macro and I just want to manipulate this for my needs.

Relevant comments inside the script:

1. Designed to be used inside Excel as a macro not with VB.  If you
   want to use from VB Add code to use Excel Object model
2. This snippet works with the the worksheet named "dublin_core" in the
   workbook.
3. This code uses "dublin_core" as the top-level XML attribute.
4. The first row of the sheet is assumed to contain the attribute
   (column) names, while the following rows are assumed to contained
   the data values
5. The first row is split on the ":" character. The first part becomes
   the "element" and the second becomes the "qualifier". If there is no
   ":" (and so no qualifier) "none" is used.
6. No data for blank cells are written to the XML file.
7. The function assumes that the first column of each row in the sheet
   has a value.  If it finds a blank first column it exits.  This is in
   order to prevent it from printing 64,000 blank rows

This is the part of the code that generates the XML file:

```
    ' create the dublin_core.xml file
      iFileNum = FreeFile
      FullPath = oDirectory & "\" & Trim(Cells(i, lCols).Value) & "\" & "dublin_core.xml"
      Open FullPath For Output As #iFileNum

      Print #iFileNum, "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
    'Print #iFileNum, "<" & sName & ">"

      Print #iFileNum, "<" & RowName & ">"

      For j = 1 To lCols - 1

      If Trim(Cells(i, j).Value) <> "" Then
        Dim vals As Variant
        vals = Split(asCols(j - 1), ":")

        If UBound(vals) = 0 Then
            ReDim vals(1)
            vals(0) = asCols(j - 1)
            vals(1) = "none"
            End If
      Print #iFileNum, "  <"; RowPrefix & " element=""" & vals(0) & """ qualifier=""" & vals(1) & """>";
       'Dim cellString As String
       cellString = Trim(Cells(i, j).Value)
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "& ", "&amp; ")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "<", "&lt;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, ">", "&gt;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "’", "&#146;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "‘", "&#145;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "'", "&apos;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, """", "&quot;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "“", "&#147;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "”", "&#148;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "–", "-")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "—", "-")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "°", "&#176;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "µ", "&#181;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "ñ", "&#241;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "±", "&#177;")
       cellString = Replace(cellString, "§", "&#x0D;")
       cellString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(cellString)



       Print #iFileNum, cellString;

       Print #iFileNum, "</" & RowPrefix & ">"
       DoEvents 'OPTIONAL
      End If
    Next j
    Print #iFileNum, " </" & RowName & ">"


    'Print #iFileNum, "</" & sName & ">"
      ExportToXML = True
      ErrorHandler:
      If iFileNum > 0 Then Close #iFileNum

      Next i
      Exit Function
      End Function
```

For the contents of my sheet for example I have these entries:

```
title        | contributor:author | citation:spage | citation:epage | description: abstract
Sample title | Doe, John          | 45             | 50             | This is a sample abstract
```

Now if I run the macro, it will generate an XML file with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <dublin_core>
    <dcvalue element="title" qualifier="none">Sample title</dcvalue>
    <dcvalue element="contributor" qualifier="author">Doe, John</dcvalue>
    <dcvalue element="citation" qualifier="spage">45</dcvalue>
    <dcvalue element="citation" qualifier="epage">50</dcvalue>
    <dcvalue element="description" qualifier="abstract">This is a sample abstract</dcvalue>
  </dublin_core>
```

Want I want to achieve is to add a language attribute such that the resulting XML would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <dublin_core>
    <dcvalue element="title" qualifier="none" language="en">Sample title</dcvalue>
    <dcvalue element="contributor" qualifier="author">Doe, John</dcvalue>
    <dcvalue element="citation" qualifier="spage">45</dcvalue>
    <dcvalue element="citation" qualifier="epage">50</dcvalue>
    <dcvalue element="description" qualifier="abstract" language="en">This is a sample abstract</dcvalue>
  </dublin_core>
```

Note that only the **title** and **description:abstract** field have the `language="en"` attribute. My question is how can I edit the code such that only the relevant columns will have the `language="en"` attribute? Previously what I did was to open the resulting XML and manually add the `language="en"` part which is very tedious if I have plenty of records in my sheet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
If Trim(Cells(i, j).Value) <> "" Then
        Dim vals As Variant
        vals = Split(asCols(j - 1), ":")

        If UBound(vals) = 0 Then
            ReDim vals(1)
            vals(0) = asCols(j - 1)
            vals(1) = "none"
            End If
      Print #iFileNum, "  <"; RowPrefix & " element=""" & vals(0) & """ qualifier=""" & vals(1) & """>";
       'Dim cellString As String
```

with:

```
Dim sContent, vals As Variant 'declare at top of procedure


If Trim(Cells(i, j).Value) <> "" Then

    vals = Split(asCols(j - 1), ":")
    ReDim Preserve vals(2) 'resize (if needed), preserving content

    If vals(1) = "" Then vals(1) = "none"

    sContent = "  <" & RowPrefix & " element=""" & vals(0) & _
             """ qualifier=""" & vals(1) & """"

    'add additional attribute?
    If Len(vals(2)) > 0 Then sContent = sContent & " language=""" & vals(2) & """"


    Print #iFileNum, sContent & ">";
```

In order to avoid hard-coding which elements get the `language="en"` I've added it to the header: e.g. -

```
title                   >> title::en
description: abstract   >> description:abstract:fr
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for this. I would like to add that the columns that should have the `language="en"` attribute are arbitrary, ie there might be other columns that should contain this attribute. I only make _title_ and _description:abstract_ as an example because they are always the column that should have that attribute.

Comment: And I wonder if it's possible not to hard code the column header in the code? Lastly, and please forgive me for my ignorance, what part or portion should I put the code above? I tried it and it created a malformed XML file and added an empty `<dcvalue element="title" qualifier="none" language="en"></dcvalue>` and `<dcvalue element="description" qualifier="abstract" language="en"></dcvalue>`.

Comment: How would you want to determine which elements get the extra attribute?  As an additional colon-separated part of the header?

Comment: Yes, Tim, that would be nice.. eg **title:en** should have the `language="en"` attribute. If it's **title:fr**, then `language="fr"`.

Comment: Has to be `title::en` or there's no way to distinguish language from qualifier

Comment: After updating the code, it looked like this: `<dcvalue element="" qualifier="none" language="en">Sample title</dcvalue>`, `<dcvalue element="" qualifier="author">Doe, John</dcvalue>`. It removed the values of the elements.

Comment: Still had a leftover `elType`  - changed to `vals(0)`

Comment: Perfect! Your tagline **SOreadytohelp** is sooo true.. Thank you so much!!!